# Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives.eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: vue.js

Asking for help why I'm getting error

```
"[vue/require-v-for-key]
Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives.eslint-plugin-vue"
```

on my post.vue

`[vue/require-v-for-key]`
Elements in iteration expect to have `'v-bind:key' directives.eslint-plugin-vue`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMjef.png)

Comment: You need to add key to v-for loop (`v-for="row in data" :key="row.id"`)

Answer (score 1):

You always have to bind a key to your element. In your case that will be the id from the row.

```
<tr 
  v-for="row in data"
  v-bind:key = "row.id"
>
```